# C# regex reduce a string with a full file path to the original string with just the file name

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a string that, among other things, contains a full file path. I'd like the strip out the directory portion of the file path and return the rest of the string. Here's an example:

"This - string - is 1 string of text with /this/full/file.path in it."

Which I'd like to reduce to:

"This - string - is 1 string of text with file.path in it."

Any ideas how to make this one work?

Using ([^/]*$) is nice but strips off all the characters before the file path. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to break it into the part before the first / and the part after with doing the substition on the second piece.

Thanks!

Comment: / (or \\) without a space before it (unless it's at string beginning)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\/.*\/
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/9

or

```
[^\s]*\/.*\/
```

If you have string like `This - string - is 1 string of text with dsfsdf/this/full/file.path in it`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/11

Comment: Nice. It had to be that simple right. So how do I use this in C#? When I use Regex and match it simply returns the "/this/full/" portion, not that outer parts like the link shows. I assume I'm missing a $ in there somewhere.

Comment: @griztown simply use `regex.replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

(MSDN Example)

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following: 
// 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile.ext' 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

Comment: If my string was only a file path, this would be great. But it isn't so was hoping to use regex. I guess I could use regex to get the file path then reduce it but seems easier to just use regex for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a Regex.

use System.IO.Path.GetFileName("/this/full/file.path");

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27551265/102937), and you didn't explain *why.*